# Splitting strings in a column into 2 columns using split and strip

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, split, strip

I am trying to split the column 'State' as follows:
where a string includes ['edit'] , this string needs to stay in the 'State' column without ['edit'], 
e.g. Alabama[edit] should become Alabama.

where a string includes '(', it needs to go in the RegionName column, stripping everything after the left bracket'('. e.g Jacksonville (Jacksonville State University)[2] should become Jacksonville.

unitown is my dataframe, with the index column and the State column.

I have tried this code:

```
for line in unitown:
    if '[edit' in line:
        unitown['State'] = unitown['State'].str.split('[', expand=True).apply(lambda x: x.str.strip()) if x.count('[edit' > 0 else np.NaN).fillna(method="ffill")
    else:
        if '(' in line:
            unitown['RegionName'] = unitown['State'].str.split('(', expand=True).apply(lambda x: x.str.strip()) if x.count('[edit' > 0 else np.NaN)
```

My result is like this, with 'State' in RegionName and the State column  unchanged. 
Please point me in the right direction to achieve the result I want? thank you for any tips.

[image]

Comment: This looks very familiar. I must have seen it in some homework of some online course...

Comment: https://realpython.com/python-data-cleaning-numpy-pandas/#cleaning-the-entire-dataset-using-the-applymap-function

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50107276/extract-string-from-column-following-a-specific-pattern

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41386443/create-pandas-dataframe-from-txt-file-with-specific-pattern